# How to initialise a polars dataframe with column names from database cursor description?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars, rust-polars

I'm connecting to Postgres Database using psycopg2 connector and using cursor property, i'm fetching the records along with their column names. Here is the code snippet of the same:

```
rds_conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host=config.RDS_HOST_NAME,
        database=config.RDS_DB_NAME,
        user=config.RDS_DB_USER,
        password=config.RDS_DB_PASSWORD,
        port=config.RDS_PORT)
    cur = rds_conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql_query)
    names = [x[0] for x in cur.description]
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
```

I'm initialising a Pandas dataframe with column names from the `cursor.description` property:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=names)
```

Instead of Pandas dataframe, if i would like to initialise a Polars dataframe with column names from the cursor.description property, how would i do it? I don't want to convert Pandas to Polars dataframe.

I tried using `polars.Dataframe.with_Columns` property but it didn't work.

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: pl.DataFrame(rows, schema=names) should work correctly what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the column names directly to the `schema` parameter of [`pl.DataFrame`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/index.html).

```py
import polars as pl

names = ["a", "b", "c"]
rows = [[0], [True], ["foo"]]

pl.DataFrame(rows, schema=names)
```

```
shape: (1, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ bool ┆ str │
╞═════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ true ┆ foo │
└─────┴──────┴─────┘
```